# parentheses and comma formatting to csv columns

Tags: python, csv, nlp, format

I used the following code

```
import itertools
f = list(itertools.combinations(['Javad', 'love', 'python'], 2))
print (f)
```

An I got the following result:

```
[('Javad', 'love'), ('Javad', 'python'), ('love', 'python')]
```

I'm looking for a way to transfer them to a csv or excel file as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
df.to_csv('your_name.csv')
```

`pandas` convert your data container to a Dataframe, based on the structure of data. for example you can convert dictionaries to Dataframe and after that you can  manipulate them or export them to csv, Excel and much more formats.